# SCSI LSI Logic vs SAS

Tags: vmware, scsi, sas

I read that LSI SAS offers better performance than traditional SCSI. While creating a virtual machine in Vmware, i have options to select either Bus Logic, LSI Logic or LSI Logic SAS. However, LSI logic is recommended by vmware inspite of the performance benefits of SAS.

[image]

Any particular reason for this recommendation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS physical hardware has better performance than regular (parallel) SCSI hardware. Which does not matter for virtualization. Meantime the parallel SCSI driver is simpler. It's code base is older (more mature). So LSI Logic adapter has better (marginally but still) support in different guest OSes. Thus the recommendation.

Comment: +1 for the 'older and thus more widely supported part'. No idea if SAS is more complex than plain old SCSI though. If this was wikipedia I would add a "reference needed" ;)